# php pgsql driver in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: php, postgresql, ubuntu, driver

What seems to be the solution in here, I am sure I installed pgsql driver on my Ubuntu 10.04.

```
root@xxxx:/# apt-get install php5-pgsql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php5-pgsql is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

But when I run my php script having pg_connect(), I always get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect() in ...
```

Any ideas please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you loaded the module in your php.ini?

Comment: feels kind of weird, under the **etc/php5/conf.d** the pgsql.ini is missing. Adding this seems to fix the problem.